# How to transparent element in element css

Tags: html, css

Today I'm working on a project, but I've to subtract the element in a element, but how can you do that?

[image]

the green element should be subtracted. But how can you do that?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Also, it is not really clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Meaning render the image while making the green part transparent?

Comment: @Victor sorry Victor, that green element should be transparent, so that you can see a bit of the phone, but the element above has a white background, but I want that one also subtracted.

Comment: @PhilipRollins yea exactly, but I struggle with the white element

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Is it an image or a HTML element?

Comment: @PhilipRollins     <img src={props.device} className={'device'} alt={props.alt_image} />
    <div className={"overlay"}>
     <div className={"image-overlay"}/>
    </div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some CSS magic you can create the shape you want:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 750px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.phone {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 700px;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  background-color: black;
}

.screen-top {
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 45px;
  top: 45px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
}

.screen-top:before {
  z-index: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  bottom: calc(100% - 30px);
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 300px 0px 300px white;
}

.screen-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 85px;
  left: 45px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 660px;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="phone"></div>
  <div class="screen-top"></div>
  <div class="screen-bottom"></div>
  <div class="screen-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can (at least approximately) get the dimensions of that part of the phone, you vould solve it with a bit of css:

```
body {
    background: goldenrod;
    height: 100vh /* optional */
} 

#map {
    position: relative; /* needed if #page != body */
    background: url(your/path/to/map);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* center the green elem horizontally */
    height: 100vh; /* optional */
}
#box {
   background: goldenrod; /* (color of page bg, so we hack transparency) */
   position: fixed; /* or absolute, as you need */
   top: 0; 
   width: 200px ; /* that phone part s width */
   height: 30px ; /* same workaround */
   border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 30px; /* the magic, complete with actual radius of phone part corner */
}
```

it should keep good for this code:

```
<body>
    <div id=map>
        <div id=box></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

adding border-radius: 30px; on #page gives it the "phone" aspect

Hope it helped :)